# Indexar variables

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de indexar una variable, pero no se cómo hacerlo.

```
// Esto busca todas las template que hay, que son 4
      var tem = document.querySelectorAll("template");

//Recorre el documento 4 veces, ya que hay 4 templates
      document.querySelectorAll("template").forEach((item,index)=>{
//Consegui meter el valor del tem0,1,2 y 3 al temp, y después sacar su innerHTML
         var temp = tem[index];
         var temp = temp.innerHTML;
      });

//Esto ya son intentos infructuosos, pero lo dejo por si iba por buen camino
/*
      for (var i = 0; i < tem.length; i++){
         var temp = i;
         temp = tem[i];

         console.log(temp);
      }
*/

//Esto es lo que pretendo simplificar sin tanto nombre, solo con numeros. tem0,tem1,tem2,tem3
      var temCard    = document.querySelector("#temp-card").innerHTML;
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;
      var temEnergy  = document.querySelector("#temp-energy").innerHTML;
      var temForm    = document.querySelector("#temp-form").innerHTML;
```

Las variables de abajo, temCard, temPower, temEnergy y temForm, quiero ponerlas como tem0,1,2 y 3.

Para ello hice un forEach, y como en el html hay 4 templates, recorre 4 veces el documento. Por ello me di cuenta que no me hacía falta un bucle for con un lenght de las template, me valía con un forEach (las pruebas infructuosas del código).

Si hago un `console.log(temp)` me saca el resultado de los 4 `template.innerHTML`, uno por uno, lo indexa bien.

Ahora lo que quiero conseguir sería algo parecido a esto:

```
var temp0 = tem[index]0
var temp1 = tem[index]1
var temp2 = tem[index]2
var temp3 = tem[index]3
```

El caso es que no se cómo hacer un bucle para indexar las variables temp.

Hasta ahora he intentado declarar una variable vacía:
`var temp = "";  // var temp;`

Y luego asignarle el valor:

`var temp = temp[index]` (ya que lo hace 4 veces, en mi cabeza pensé que asignaría del 0 al 3 ello solo)

¿Cómo podría hacerlo más simple?

### **[EDIT]**

Intenté simplificarlo al máximo y, este es el resultado

```
constructor(id, idtxt, params){

      var tem = document.querySelectorAll("template");

      var tem0 = tem[0].innerHTML, tem1 = tem[1].innerHTML, tem2 = tem[2].innerHTML, tem3 = tem[3].innerHTML;

      console.log(tem0);
      console.log(tem1);
      console.log(tem2);
      console.log(tem3);
   }
```

Sin quitar los console.log, no hay forma de simplificarlo mas, ¿no?

Comment: No acabo de entender qué quieres hacer, pero además no entiendo para qué. Si tienes ya un array con los valores, me parece mucho más cómodo trabajar con `tem[n]` que tener muchas variables `tempN`, sobre las que es mucho más complicado iterar

Comment: Vale, gracias a ti lo simplifiqué un poco más, no me hace falta el bucle forEach. Pero igualmente, tengo que conseguir asignar la, por ejemplo, variable 1 = tem[0], variable2 = tem[1], etc. Pero veo que no hay forma de hacerlo mediante bucles

Comment: Sigues creando las variables, que es la parte que no entiendo. ¿Por qué usar tem0 en lugar de tem[0]?

Comment: Porque estoy aprendiendo y me cuesta muchísimo no usar variables para todo XD
Gracias por tu ayuda :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te mencionan en los comentarios, es difícil entender tu objetivo, aun más porque parece ir en contra de cualquier lógica en programación. Muchos lenguajes ni siquiera te permiten crear nombres de variables dinámicamente. Diría que esta es una mala práctica pero también hay cierto "arte" en abusar correctamente de las cosas "malas" de javascript :)

No hay ningún problema en usar tus bucles siempre que continúes usando `var`. En tu  último ejemplo parece que sabes de antemano que siempre habrán 4 "templates" y que estan siempre en la misma posición. Si eso es el caso entonces no hay necesidad de ningún bucle tampoco. (protip: usa nombre de variables claras como hiciste en tu otro ejemplo, es más legible)

```
let tem = document.querySelectorAll("template");
let temCard    = tem[0].innerHTML;
let temPower   = tem[1].innerHTML;
let temEnergy  = tem[2].innerHTML;
let temForm    = tem[3].innerHTML;
```

Esto es mucho más claro y legible.

Si por alguna otra razón "necesitas" que tus variables tengan ese número porque después necesitas la referencia al index, entonces yo preferiría "guardar" esa información en un estructura y no atarla al nombre de una variable. ej: quédate con el array incial `tem` y solo llama `tem[x].innerHTML` hasta el momento que lo necesites. El index está implicito por default al ser un array. Por lo que `"tem[1]"` sería lo mismo que `tem1`. No hay necesidad de ponerlo en su propia variable.

Si existe otra razón que no hemos entendido con gusto hazlo saber y editaré la respuesta. Saludos y suerte :)

Comment: No no, lo has clavado. Voy a usar la segunda opción, ya que me resulta más cómoda y me libro de asignar variables innecesarias, que una vez leí que cuantas menos variables tenga un documento, o cuanto antes mueran, mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es tener los strings (el innerHTML) de cada template, podrías hacer algo como

```
const tem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("template"));
const templateStrings = tem.map(elem => elem.innerHTML);
```

Comment: No es lo que bsucaba, pero me lo apunto igualmente. Lo que haces es meter el innerHTML en el array por lo que veo, lo que intentaba hacer es otra cosa, poner como variable tem0 = tem[0].innerHTML  Para trabajar más cómodamente, vaya, y lo que quería hacer era que los nombres de las varibales tem[0,1,2,3] se asignaran dinámicamente. Pero vamos, tardas menos haciendolo a mano en linea y ya.

Comment: Lamentablemente no tenía tiempo para darte una respuesta (tus preguntas a veces rayan en "demasiado amplia"), pero vi mucho código que se podría hacer por iteración o extraer a una función para llamarla varias veces en lugar de copiar y pegar lo mismo. Al final te acostumbrarás a trabajar con arrays de datos ;)

Comment: Esa es la idea Pablo, y lo siento por las Biblias que pregunto XD